# How to de/encrypt user data with attr_encrypted and authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authlogic

I have a user model using authlogic and a model storing some confidential data for each user.
To secure the system, I would like to de/encrypt the attributes of the latter model using attr_encrypted.
I want to have a system that is secure, if somebody manages to steal the entire database and application source code.

My question is: What is the best way to generate the password for attr_encrypted? And how do I keep it in "memory" during the login session, so that I can de/encrypt when it is necessary?

I thought of following:

- Generate a random password when a user registers, encrypt it with the users password and save it in the database.
- Whenever the user logs in, use his password to decrypt the random password.
- Save the random password in a cookie, so that personal data can be de/encrypted whenever necessary.

Do you have any suggestions or better ideas? In particular I am unsure about the last bullet point...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using authlogic, it manages the password stuff, sessions, etc., and you don't need to worry about the password decryption. It's automatic.